# Count to in ViewPort

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, count

I work on creating a count up number like in this link:
Themeforest Link

But there are many problems:

**First problem:** I need to do animation when the element is shown in the view port.

**Second problem:** When I scroll again, the element number is animation from up to down and the duration is not working well. I don't know why this problem is occurs.

The code is below:

```js
function countUp() {
    $('.count').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 4000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
            }
        });
    });
}
$(function () {
    "user strict";
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        console.log("scroll top=" + $(this).scrollTop());
        console.log("div offset top=" + $("div").offset().top);
        var scrolling = $(this).scrollTop(),
            divoffset = $(".count").offset().top;
        if (scrolling > divoffset - 300) {
            countUp();
        }
    })
})
```

```css
body{
    height:4000px;
}
.count{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:200px;
    border:1px solid #10f880;
    margin:1000px auto 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count">1000</div>
```

**Note:** I've tried this [Stack Overflow suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455490/animate-counter-when-in-viewport), but I'd like to understand the idea, thank you:

Answer (score 3):

```js
function countUp() {
$('.count').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
      Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
      duration: 4000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function(now) {
        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
      }
    });
  });
}
$(function() {
  "user strict";
  var bAnimate = true;
  $(".count").css ("opacity", "0.0");
  
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    // console.log("scroll top=" + $(this).scrollTop());
    // console.log("div offset top=" + $("div").offset().top);
    var scrolling = $(this).scrollTop(),
      divoffset = $(".count").offset().top,
      screenBottom = scrolling + $(window).height(), 
      elemBottom = divoffset + $(".count").outerHeight (); // 
    if (screenBottom > elemBottom) {
      if (bAnimate) {
         $(".count").css ("opacity", "1.0");
        countUp();
        bAnimate = false;
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 4000px;
}

.count {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #10f880;
  margin: 1000px auto 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count">1000</div>
```

Execute the function when bottom of the screen(window height) is greater than bottom of the element(top of element + outerHeight).
Use boolean to stop the function from executing second time.

Comment: Thank you very Much, But There simple Problem That When I Hold The Scroll Bar That No Animation Is Execute and i'd Like User To See Animation, What I Mean That When I Scroll I See The Max Number Then The Number animation

Comment: Answer updated to add that option. Just hide the element using opacity or display property and show right before executing the counting function