# jQuery animtion stops when user scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, viewport

I'm using multiple number elements on my site which are counting up after hitting the visible area of the viewport.

That part works until the user manually scrolls the page. If the user scrolls up or down, the animation stops for a second and repeats when the user don't scroll anymore. It looks very buggy.

If I try to replicate the problem in a fiddle, the same code always works without the "stuttering"?

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(function($, win) {
    $.fn.inViewport = function(cb) {
      return this.each(function(i, el) {
        function visPx() {
          var H = $(this).height(),
            r = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
            t = r.top,
            b = r.bottom;
          return cb.call(el, Math.max(0, t > 0 ? H - t : (b < H ? b : H)));
        }
        visPx();
        $(win).on("resize scroll", visPx);
      });
    };
  }(jQuery, window));

  $(".fig-number").inViewport(function(px) {
    // if px>0 (entered V.port) and
    // if prop initNumAnim flag is not yet set = Animate numbers
    if (px > 0 && !this.initNumAnim) {
      this.initNumAnim = true; // Set flag to true to prevent re-running the same animation

      $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
      }, {
        duration: 10000,
        step: function(now) {
          $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.spacer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spacer">
  scroll down
</div>
<div class="number-box">
  <h1 class="fig-number">1000</h1>
  <h1 class="fig-number">1500</h1>
</div>
<div class="spacer">
  scroll down
</div>
<div class="number-box">
  <h1 class="fig-number">2000</h1>
  <h1 class="fig-number">2500</h1>
</div>
<div class="spacer">
  scroll down
</div>
<div class="number-box">
  <h1 class="fig-number">3000</h1>
  <h1 class="fig-number">3500</h1>
</div>
```

The working fiddle (same code): https://jsfiddle.net/JSCray/r7g0vn93/3/

Comment: As I said, it works in the fiddle. Not on the site itself.

Comment: Humm... if the fiddle works as expected, how could we know what bugs you on the real page? How many elements do you animate? Perhaps (among other heavy stuff you do on that page) assigning too many scroll listeners could represent a perf. killer...

Comment: yes, you're right. It's hard to say. I thought there was a problem in my code or maybe there is something that could prevent the stuttering. On the site are only 5 elements per page max.

Comment: I suggest you to explore a bit how to use Chrome's Developer tools **Performance** tab. Create a record and inspect which processes cause the page slowdown. There are really good tutorials out in the wild if you never used this Chrome feature.